# Cross-origin isolation in a Firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, web-extension, sharedarraybuffer, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy

In Chrome, one can make an extension cross-origin isolated by adding the following to `manifest.json`:

```json
{
    ...
    "cross_origin_embedder_policy": {
        "value": "require-corp"
    },
    "cross_origin_opener_policy": {
        "value": "same-origin"
    },
    ...
}
```

However, this is not supported on Firefox. I need to use `SharedArrayBuffer`, so I need cross-origin isolation. How do I make an extension cross-origin isolated on Firefox?